# Accordion Collapses Immediately After I Expand a Row

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I am creating a drop down table with Accordion on my SharePoint site. I referenced this page (P.S. I hate W3Schools) [https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_accordions.asp#:~:text=An%20accordion%20is%20used%20to%20show%20%28and%20hide%29,of%20button%20to%20open%20and%20close%20the%20content%3A](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_accordions.asp#:%7E:text=An%20accordion%20is%20used%20to%20show%20%28and%20hide%29,of%20button%20to%20open%20and%20close%20the%20content%3A)

Everytime I expand a row on SharePoint, the page refreshes and immediately collapses the row. When I do it in JSFiddle or this snippet, it works fine. Why is that.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.previous {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: #b3ab7d;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}

.backbtn{
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>System and Information Integrity (SI)</h2>

<button class="accordion">SI.1.210 Identify, report, and correct information and information system flaws in a timely manner.</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">SI.1.211 Provide protection from malicious code at appropriate locations within organizational information systems.</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">S1.1.212 Update malicious code protection mechanisms when new releases are available.</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">SI.1.213 Perform periodic scans of the information system and real-time scans of files from external sources as files are downloaded, opened, or executed</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div class="backbtn">
<a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Go Back</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the attribute `type="button"` to your buttons, to prevent them from behaving as "submit" buttons and submitting the form data to the server (which is what is causing your page refresh).

```
<button type="button" class="accordion">Description</button>
```

From the [MDN page on the button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) (emphasis mine):

> type
>
> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - submit: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified** for buttons associated with
>   a `<form>`, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.
> - reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values, like `<input type="reset">`. (This behavior tends to annoy users.)
> - button: The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the
>   element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

If you inspect your HTML, you will see almost undoubtedly that what you have added to SharePoint exists inside a `<form>` element that is just part of SP pages, which is why the `submit` behavior happens if you don't specify your button type as something other.